# Declaring a Variable in Python without giving a value

Tags: python

```
print ("please enter a number : ")
Num1= None
Num2= None
sum = 0
input (Num1)
print(Num1)
```

I tried the above code and although the code works it gave me the result:

Please Enter A Number:
None

I do not want the "None" in the output.

Is there a way to fix this problem?

Comment: why not just use `Num1 = input("please enter a number : ")` ?

Comment: Ok, I will try! Thx

Comment: `input` will try to display the argument as a prompt to the user and return whatever the user enters, as a string

Answer (score 0):

```
print("please enter a number : ")
Num1 = None
Num2 = None

Num1 = int(input())
print(Num1)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In short, Python doesn't have explicit declaration, such as `let name` in JS.

> Python lacks declarations and allows name binding operations to occur anywhere within a code block.

[resolution-of-names](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names)